# How to set strict date format "DD/MM/YYYY" using SpreadSheetGear 2012

Tags: c#, excel, date, spreadsheetgear

I use spreadsheetgear 2012 version 7.0.5.140 and have problem with date column.

The formatting of date after opening generated excel file depends on system culture settings and I would like to enforce date presentation to have specific format "DD/MM/YYYY" regardless system culture settings.

What is correct way to enforce date formatting in date column? I was trying different implementations i.e. [How to set default date format when load an xls file to SpreadSheetGear workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087148/how-to-set-default-date-format-when-load-an-xls-file-to-spreadsheetgear-workbook) unsuccessfully ...

Before loading the data, I set up number format but it is ignored on computers with different culture settings.

```
worksheet.Cells["H:H"].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"; // that column is populated with DateTime
```

Comment: show your unsuccessful code.

Comment: @cyboashu I use only one setting to choose formatting DateTime column, I have included this in main thread